# Telegram python check key value from JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

i'm creating a telegram bot using pyhton, specifically the following module

> https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot

What i want to do is:

- send input to the bot
- read the update object to analyze each field
- check if 'text' key is present
- do something if yes

My current python implementation:

```
def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    if 'text' in update.message:
        update.message.reply_text('I found your key value you are looking for')
    else:
        update.message.reply_text('Key not found')

def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater(MY_TOKEN)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Structure of `update` object:

```
{
   "update_id":id_update,
   "message":{
      "message_id":1579,
      "date":1615193338,
      "chat":{
         "id":id_chat,
         "type":"private",
         "username":"XXX",
         "first_name":"XXX"
      },
      "text":"Hello Bot",
      "entities":[
         
      ],
      "caption_entities":[
         
      ],
      "photo":[
         
      ],
      "new_chat_members":[
         
      ],
      "new_chat_photo":[
         
      ],
      "delete_chat_photo":false,
      "group_chat_created":false,
      "supergroup_chat_created":false,
      "channel_chat_created":false,
      "from":{
         "id":id_chat,
         "first_name":"xxx",
         "is_bot":false,
         "username":"xxx",
         "language_code":"it"
      }
   }
}
```

When i test it i didn't get any output from the bot, it seems like it is ignoring the if/else condition.
If i print the `update.message.text` i see correctly the input sent to the bot.

Thank you all

> EDIT

I found the solution, i had to change the filter passed to MessageHandler in this way

```
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all, echo))
```

Thanks anyway for the help

Comment: May I know why you're checking 'text' key in update.message?

Comment: found the solution..changed Filter.text with Filter.all ..in this way every message is passed to echo function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit is very likely not the actual solution. Using `Filters.all` instead of `Filters.text & ~Filters.command` just says that the `MessageHandler` will catch *any* message and not just messages that contain text and don't start with a botcommand.

The problem rather is that `'text' in update.message` can't work as `update.message` is a `telegram.Message` object and not iterable. Therefore `'text' in update.message` will probably throw an error, which you don't see as you have neither logging enabled nor an error handler registered (see the PTB readme and wiki, respectively for info on logging & error handlers).

My guess is that changing to `'text' in update.message.text` should do the trick.